# How to get month from Material design Datepicker Android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a datepicker from material design, its opening well in the app.
Now how can i get for example the selected month from the datepicker.

Initialize the datepicker:

```
val datePicker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()
    .setTitleText("Kies een datum")
    .setSelection(MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds())
    .build()
```

On button hit the calendar opens:

```
fun pickDate() {
    binding.DatepickerButton.setOnClickListener {

        datePicker.show(activity?.supportFragmentManager!!, datePicker.toString())


    }
}
```

so it shows, but i cannot get the data from it.

Answer (score 1):

For Java 8, you can use Date/Time API

```
binding.DatepickerButton.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
    var dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM", Locale.getDefault())
    val month = dateFormatter.format(
                Instant.ofEpochMilli(it)
                    .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate()
            )
}
```

Otherwise, you can use `SimpleDateFormatter`

```
 binding.DatepickerButton.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
     val calendar = Calendar.getInstance() 
     val simpleDateFormatter = SimpleDateFormat("MM", Locale.getDefault())
     calendar.time = Date(it)
     val month = simpleDateFormatter.format(calendar.time)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this click positive button click listener. after getting the date you can extract a month from it.

```
 binding.DatepickerButton.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
     val (startOfRange, endOfRange) = it   // in case date range operation
     val date = it //  single select date
     String dateString = DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy", new Date(date)).toString();
 }
```